# shared preferences on image view state

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How can I save the state or the image of my clickable ImageView with SharedPreferences or anything else. I want to show the saved state after returning into the activity. I want to achieve something like the favorite button in some application :

In my MainActivity:

```
final ImageView like = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.like);

    //set the click listener
    like.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View button) {
            //Set the button's appearance
            button.setSelected(!button.isSelected());

            if (button.isSelected()) {
                like.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starf);

            } else {
                like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star);
            }
        }
    });
```

and my Layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/like"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/star"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use something like:

```
       public void setButtonState(boolean selected){
             SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences();
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
             editor.putBoolean(Constants.LIKE_BUTTON_STATE_SELECTED, selected);
             editor.apply();
        }

       public boolean isButtonSelected(){
         return getSharedPreferences().getBoolean(Constants.LIKE_BUTTON_STATE_SELECTED, false);
       }
```

Then, in order to set the value:

```
final ImageView like = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.like);
like.setSelected(isButtonSelected());

//set the click listener
    like.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View button) {
            //Set the button's appearance
            button.setSelected(!button.isSelected());
            setButtonState(button.isSelected); //Here you store the value
            if (button.isSelected()) {
                like.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starf);

            } else {
                like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you but it shows error on `LIKE_BUTTON_STATE_SELECTED` , what should I write instead of that ? , and what should I write in `getSharedPreferences()`? because it says String name , mode ...

Comment: There you have to put a unique String key, it doesn't matter actually what it is, as long as you use the same for setting and getting the value

Comment: Yes, it does. Please refer to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) for further info.

Comment: @Vahidpr if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.